# How to turn off buffering in IIS for MVC 4 Web API application

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC 4 Web API application running on IIS 7. To analyse why the application is slow, I tried profiling the application and found no major bottlenecks. Apparently, the response is getting buffered and the wait time before flush is causing the delay. I learnt that there a setting - aspBufferingOn which can be set to false in IIS to disable buffering. Documentation says that this setting should be available under "ASP" feature in IIS Manager's Feature view. But I dont see a feature by name "ASP" there.

[image: screenshot]

Where can I set the value of "aspBufferOn" setting for my Web API application in IIS Manager?

Comment: Web API's (WebHost) buffer policy is driven by `WebHostBufferPolicySelector`...what is your scenario? Are you trying to download a large file or something else?

Comment: My application exposes methods that return objects. ie HTTPResponseMessage contains object of type ObjectContent. The ContentLength property is null. Could not find a reliable way to compute the length of the object (as length could vary by encoding used) and TrygetContentLength() exposed by the object returns false/-1, so decided to turn off buffering in IIS

Comment: @Kiran Wouldn't turning off aspBufferingOn parameter in IIS solve the problem? If it wont, how do I use the WebHostBufferPolicySelector to turn off buffering?

Comment: By default `ObjectContent` is buffered to catch any serialization errors and embed this error info in the response msg. If `ObjectContent` is non-buffered, then you would loose this capability and in case of any serialization errors, the client would just see a disconnection. Why do you want to switch off buffering, is your object huge and consuming lot of memory? You can override the default implementation of `WebHostBufferPolicySelector`'s `UserBufferedOutputStream` method to conditionally buffer/non-buffer for specific requests..however please keep in mind of the above scenario

Answer (score 1):

See Filip W answer first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14906901/1241400

Regarding to your ASP feature question

You need to go to **Start** then in search type **Turn Windows Features on or off** and enable it.

[image]

Reference: [ASP Limits](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/limits)

More on **AspBufferingOn**

> This property specifies whether output from an ASP application will be
>   buffered. If the value is TRUE (default), all output from the
>   application is collected in the buffer before the buffer is flushed to
>   the client browser. If this property is set to FALSE, output from ASP
>   scripts will be written to client browser as it becomes available.
>
> With buffering on, the ASP application will have to completely process
>   the ASP script before any output is received by the client browser.
>   For this reason, applications for which buffering has been turned on
>   could seem slower to users than those applications for which buffering
>   is turned off, even though the total time taken for the buffered
>   script is less. Therefore, if buffering is turned on, you should
>   consider using the Response.Flush method to pass the user pieces of
>   content as the script is being processed.
>
> Note   If buffering is turned off, any methods that modify existing
>   HTTP headers, or generate new headers, must be executed before the
>   content body is sent to the client browser. If buffering is turned on,
>   this restriction is unnecessary.
>
> Important   If you installed IIS 5.0 by upgrading from a previous
>   version of IIS, the default setting for this property will be FALSE,
>   not TRUE.

- **Data type**    Boolean
- **Default value**    TRUE
- **Inheritance**  Inheritable